# Question migration

Tags: discussion, migration

Shouldn't [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48624/what-are-zombie-processes) question be migrated to unix.stackexchange.com? As I see it almost has nothing to do with Ubuntu as a Linux distro, but rather Linux in itself.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be migrated because: a. Its too old. We don't migrate old questions. b. It's perfectly on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

It should not be migrated for two reasons:

- The fact that it is more on-topic on another site doesn't mean it's off-topic here. The subject of the question applies to Ubuntu in full regard. Moreover, if the OP only uses Ubuntu distributions this is even a better place than UL, because all the answers regarding other OSs like BSD/Sun, etc. might be totally irrelevant to him.
- Old answered questions are of no value to be migrated. All the current answers/comments are applicable to Ubuntu and if it gets migrated to a site with a much broader scope current posts might be criticized for being too narrow on how things work in Ubuntu (if applicable - I'm not able to oversee that now). That's not nice.